# How can we directly run the OnPsnHelp event (or invoke it) in a property page ourselves?

Tags: visual-c++, cmfcpropertypage

I have been working through my app adding the `OnHelpInfo` message handler. This is not because my app will support context help. Rather, I wanted to intercept the F1 key and then simply call the existing "Help" code that is triggered when then press the dialog button or menu item. Example:

```
#pragma warning (suppress : 26434)
BOOL CBrotherExcludeDlg::OnHelpInfo(HELPINFO* pHelpInfo)
{
    OnButtonHelp();

    // return CResizingDialog::OnHelpInfo(pHelpInfo);
    return TRUE;
}
```

My problem is for the property pages. They handle the displaying on the help topics by using a different mechanism. Example:

```
void CCalendarSettingsGooglePage::OnPsnHelp(NMHDR* hdr, LRESULT* res)
{
    theApp.DisplayHelpTopic(_T("msa-options-calendars.html"));
}
```

It uses the `PSN_HELP` handler. When I add the `OnHelpInfo` to the property page, I am now not sure how to simply run the `OnPsnHelp` event. I am trying to avoid having two places where I call `DisplayHelpTopic`.

How can we either directly call `OnPsnHelp` (like I called the Help button click handler function) or invoke it via a message?

---

This is the boiler plate code:

```
BOOL CPropertyPage::OnNotify(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, LRESULT* pResult)
{
    ASSERT(pResult != NULL);
    NMHDR* pNMHDR = (NMHDR*)lParam;

    // allow message map to override
    if (CDialog::OnNotify(wParam, lParam, pResult))
        return TRUE;

    // don't handle messages not from the page/sheet itself
    if (pNMHDR->hwndFrom != m_hWnd && pNMHDR->hwndFrom != ::GetParent(m_hWnd))
        return FALSE;

    // handle default
    switch (pNMHDR->code)
    {
    case PSN_SETACTIVE:
        {
            CPropertySheet* pSheet = GetParentSheet();
            if (pSheet != NULL && !(pSheet->m_nFlags & WF_CONTINUEMODAL) && !(pSheet->m_bModeless) && !(pSheet->m_psh.dwFlags & PSH_AEROWIZARD))
                *pResult = -1;
            else
                *pResult = OnSetActive() ? 0 : -1;
        }
        break;
    case PSN_KILLACTIVE:
        *pResult = !OnKillActive();
        break;
    case PSN_APPLY:
        *pResult = OnApply() ? PSNRET_NOERROR : PSNRET_INVALID_NOCHANGEPAGE;
        break;
    case PSN_RESET:
        OnReset();
        break;
    case PSN_QUERYCANCEL:
        *pResult = !OnQueryCancel();
        break;
    case PSN_WIZNEXT:
        *pResult = MapWizardResult(OnWizardNext());
        break;
    case PSN_WIZBACK:
        *pResult = MapWizardResult(OnWizardBack());
        break;
    case PSN_WIZFINISH:
        *pResult = reinterpret_cast<LRESULT>(OnWizardFinishEx());       
        break;
    case PSN_HELP:
        SendMessage(WM_COMMAND, ID_HELP);
        break;

    default:
        return FALSE;   // not handled
    }

    return TRUE;    // handled
}
```

So I don't get that. If I use `SendMessage(WM_COMMAND, ID_HELP);` the response in the software is a popup `Failed to launch help`.

Comment: @AdrianMole That doesn't work. But it occurs to me that I don't use the parameters to the function. So simply calling this `OnPsnHelp(nullptr, nullptr);` works fine.

Comment: That may be a quick fix, and it may work. But it's dodgy, indeed, unless you put a check for those `nullptr` values in the handler. WHat if someone else takes over your code and uses the pointers?

Comment: @AdrianMole That is a possibility. But this is a personal project. Maybe we can look at the property page boiler plate code and see what it does to invoke the handler.

Comment: @AdrianMole This page (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/psn-help) says it is sent in the form of a `WM_NOTIFY` message.

Comment: @AdrianMole *construct a valid `NMHDR` structure*. Now that is the task to resolve!

Comment: I've outlined the process for constructing that structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in the comments, you *could* just call your `OnPsnHelp` function with two `nullptr` values, because that function doesn't actually use those parameters. However, *this is asking for trouble* if, in a future version of your software, the `OnPsnHelp` is modified so that it *does* use those.

So, you should construct an appropriate `PSHNOTIFY` structure and pass the address of that, and of a valid return-code variable, in your 'proxy' call of `OnPsnHelp`. The construction of that `PSHNOTIFY` structure is quite trivial; it is simply an `NMHDR` structure followed by an *unused* `lParam` item.

Here's a possible implementation:

```cpp
BOOL CCalendarSettingsGooglePage::OnHelpInfo(HELPINFO*)
{
    PSHNOTIFY psns;
    psns.lParam = 0; // The docs say this contains no information.
    psns.hdr.hwndFrom = GetParent()->GetSafeHwnd(); // The parent P/Sheet
    psns.hdr.idFrom = IDHELP; // Not sure what this should REALLY be?
    #pragma warning(suppress: 26454) // For: #define PSN_HELP (PSN_FIRST-5)
    psns.hdr.code = PSN_HELP; // One would assume this is the correct code!
    LRESULT result;
    OnPsnHelp(&psns.hdr, &result); // Make the call.
    return TRUE; // Or possibly: return static_cast<BOOL>(result);
}
```

---

From the [M/S docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/psn-help):

> *lParam*
>
> Pointer to a `PSHNOTIFY` structure that contains information about the
> notification code. This structure contains an `NMHDR` structure as its
> first member, **hdr**. The **hwndFrom** member of this `NMHDR`
> structure contains the handle to the property sheet. The **lParam**
> member of the `PSHNOTIFY` structure does not contain any information.

---

Here are the definitions of the `PSHNOTIFY` and `NMHDR` structures:

```cpp
typedef struct _PSHNOTIFY
{
    NMHDR hdr;
    LPARAM lParam;
} PSHNOTIFY, *LPPSHNOTIFY;

typedef struct tagNMHDR
{
    HWND      hwndFrom;
    UINT_PTR  idFrom;
    UINT      code;         // NM_ code
}   NMHDR;
```

Comment: Of course, you could always put a temporary message box in your `OnPsnHelp` to show what the `idFrom` and `lParam` members of the structure are when the *system* calls it.

Comment: Thanks for this. Will look into this later this morning.

Comment: Those values are both 0. But this will not compile. The `OnPsnHelp` call wants the parameter to be a `NMHDR*`. Also, we can use `GetParentSheet()` instead of `GetParent()`.

Comment: We have to use: `OnPsnHelp(&psns.hdr, &result);`.

Comment: And a pragma: `#pragma warning (suppress : 26454)` just before the line `psns.hdr.code = PSN_HELP;`

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Thanks. Passing the wrong pointer type was a bit careless of me; and the weird way Microsoft define their notification codes also escaped me. Edited.

Comment: To confirm, it seems that those other values you were not sure about can be left as 0.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Yeah - The `lParam` can be (I guess) anything; and `idFrom` is also probably not used, though the `ID_HELP` value seems more suitable, and least IMHO.